# python groupby multiple columns, count and percentage

Tags: python, pandas

I have a test dataframe:

```
data= (['a','test1', 'cat'], ['a','test1', 'cat'], ['b', 'test2', 'dog'])
pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['col1','col2','col3'])
```

How would I be able to group by col1, col2 and col3 as well as having the count and percentage of each group, sorted with the highest at the top?

The expected output is:

```
a test1 cat 2 66.6
b test2 dog 1 33.3
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Both solution works equally well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another way using [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
g = df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'],sort=False)
s = g.ngroup().value_counts(normalize=True,sort=False)
s.index = g.groups.keys()

out = g.size().to_frame('Size').assign(Percentage=s.mul(100).round(2)).reset_index()
```

---

```
  col1   col2 col3  Size  Percentage
0    a  test1  cat     2       66.67
1    b  test2  dog     1       33.33
```

Comment: This is great, I did not even think about `ngroup`

Comment: Much better than the more iterative approach I took.

Comment: very nice use of `ngroup` :) +1

Comment: Hi I have tried this code on my real dataset, it seems that it has the error where the larger size has a percentage smaller than a row with a smaller size.

Comment: Hi, the larger group has a smaller percentage in this case.

Comment: @user90831 Got it, sorry for the inconvinience , `value_counts` be defaults sorts descending order , please try now , I edited a little

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df_final = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index(name='counts')    
df_final['percentage'] = df_final.counts / len(df) * 100

Out[78]:
  col1   col2 col3  counts  percentage
0    a  test1  cat       2    66.6667
1    b  test2  dog       1    33.3333
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# sample data
data= (['a','test1', 'cat'], ['a','test1', 'cat'], ['b', 'test2', 'dog'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['col1','col2','col3'])

# create a function that calls df and the len of the frame
def my_func(df, l=len(df)):
    data = {
        'count': df['col3'].count(),
        'percent': df['col3'].count() / l*100
    }

    return pd.Series(data)

# groupby and apply the function and sort values
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).apply(my_func).sort_values('percent', ascending=False)

                 count    percent
col1 col2  col3                  
a    test1 cat     2.0  66.666667
b    test2 dog     1.0  33.333333
```